# SQL - get the values between the curly brackets from a string

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, logic, temp-tables

I am using SQL Server 2008.

How can i get the values in between "{" and "}" from a string and put it into a temp table

```
DECLARE @myString VARCHAR(100) = 'my value {Year}{Month}{Day} sample'
create table #temp(Tag varchar(50))
```

I need to insert "Year", "Month", "Day" into the temp table from the string @myString

Is there any logic to do this?

Comment: is the string always the same but has different Dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all `{` with `<X>` and all `}` with `</X>`. Cast to XML and shred the xml in a cross apply using `nodes()`. Extract the value using `value()`.

```
declare @myString varchar(100) = 'my value {Year}{Month}{Day} sample';

select T2.X.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
from (select cast(replace(replace((select @myString for xml path('')), '{', '<X>'), '}', '</X>') as xml).query('.')) as T1(X)
  cross apply T1.X.nodes('/X/text()') as T2(X);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18347)

Comment: Very nice creative solution, didn't even think of using xml-functions in this way